# i cannot setup and log into my raspberrypi

Tags: command-line

I am having trouble setting up my raspberry pi. it is a Pi3 model B running  Rasbian-jessie(latest release). I can ping it using windows 8 command prompt and I can obtain it IP address but when I try to ssh using putty I get a repetitive error 'network error. software caused connection abort'. Now I can't get access to it's command line. In short I can't even log in.

What should I do?; I am stuck at the first step.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi comes with ssh disabled by default. You need to connect a keyboard and screen to it first and do it manually. You can do the following:

Enter `sudo raspi-config` in the terminal, first select *Interfacing* options, then navigate to *ssh*, press Enter and select *Enable or disable* ssh server.

You'll be able to access it from your PC afterwards.

Remember that by default, user is pi and password is raspberry. As a good practice these should be changed. It could be also good to consider changing the port to access ssh, 22 by default, for security reasons.

EDIT: Also, as a polite reminder, I think this post should have been placed under the raspberry pi section.

Comment: Alternative would be a serial connection even if not everyone has the right tools at hand (e.g. a TTL serial dongle).

Comment: True that, but thought the other option was easier :)

Comment: I would not worry about port numbers, but you should set up a key, and disable password based ssh, on the server (pi).

Comment: You can also do it by plugging the SD into a PC and editing the config files. However this is hopeless with MS-Windows. You would need some sort of Unix such as Gnu/Linux, UNIX, or mac OSX.